# Is it possible to save in a log everything the system outputs when I turn it on?

Tags: logs, startup, prompt, output

I am using a BeagleBone Black without any screen. It works fine, but sometimes when I turn it on it hangs and have to reset. I do not know why this is happening and since I cannot see whatever it is doing when it is starting, I would like to save everything that it is actually doing to a log file so when this happens I can reset and read it, so I understand what is failing. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Run `syslogd` to record system log.

Rest daemons may have record of their own log files.

Read man pages of `syslogd` for more in depth logging

Comment: `man syslog`, not `man syslogd`?

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?syslogd+8

Comment: Strange. On my system (Kubuntu 14.04) `man syslogd` gives nothing. There's also no `/etc/syslog.conf`, so maybe it's just not installed. Also, that link often calls it `sysklogd`, which is odd.